# C++: Partially specializing template's type parameter as another template class's member-type

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

I have a template struct `SFoo` that contains a member struct `SZug`:

```
template <typename tTYPE>
struct SFoo
  {
    struct SZug {};
  };
```

I have another struct `SBar` that takes a type parameter:

```
template <typename tTYPE>
struct SBar
  { /* stuff */ };
```

I would like to specialize `SBar` using `SZug` for the type parameter, like so:

```
template <typename tTYPE>
struct SBar<typename SFoo<tTYPE>::SZug>
  { /* different stuff */ };
```

This doesn't compile - LLVM outputs:

> non-deducible template parameter 'tTYPE'

While a compiler could easily deduce this if it wished, I'm guessing it's just that the C++ spec would need to specifically cover this case.

Is there any way to achieve this?
(note: I'm currently working around it by moving `SZug` outside of `SFoo` and using a `using` declaration, but it's ugly.)

Comment: What do you intend to do after? It is not clear to me what you expect the "specialization" to do. Can you show us how you would declare a variable of the non-specialized and specialized `SBar`?

Comment: I'm actually using these purely as trait types, so they're never actually instantiated. Bar simply provides a constexpr member pointer for another (not mentioned) class (plus a few other things). Usually the member pointer needs to be explicitly specified, but for the `SZug` specialization it can be determined. -- (Ultimately this is all to do with generating N-to-N generic embedded containers from 1-to-N generic containers - the member pointer points to the container or node info "embedded" (i.e. a member variable) in the user's type).

Comment: I you can slightly modified `SZug` to detect it, it is pretty easy to do what you want using SFINAE (see my answer). If you cannot, I am not sure there is a way to detect that `tTYPE` is the `SFoo<T>::SZug` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understood what you want to do, but you could try the following (it only requires adding a specific attributes to `SZug`:

```
template <typename tTYPE>
struct SFoo {
    struct SZug {
        // Add this to be able to obtain SFoo<T> from SFoo<T>::SZug
        using type = tTYPE;
    };
};
```

Then a small template to check if a type is a `SFoo<T>::SZug`:

```
template <typename tTYPE, typename Enabler = void>
struct is_SZug: public std::false_type { };

template <typename tTYPE>
struct is_SZug<tTYPE, typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_same<tTYPE, typename SFoo<typename tTYPE::type>::SZug>{}
>::type>: public std::true_type { };
```

And a slight modification to the `SBar` template to enable the "specialization" if the type is a `SZug`:

```
template <typename tTYPE, typename Enabler = void>
struct SBar
  { static void g(); };

template <typename tTYPE>
struct SBar<tTYPE, typename std::enable_if<is_SZug<tTYPE>{}>::type>
  { static void f(); };
```

A little check:

```
void f () {
  SBar<int>::g();
  SBar<SFoo<int>::SZug>::f();
}
```

**Note:** You could also directly set `SFoo<T>` as the `type` attribute in `SFoo<T>::SZug`, you would simply need to change the second argument of `std::is_same` a little.

Comment: Yep, this does solve the problem, tyvm. For my current problem, adding the `using type = tTYPE;` is pretty simple. The extra parameter on `SBar` is more annoying, but still do-able. I'm currently deciding whether this is tidier than my current fix. - If no better answer arrives by tomorrow I'll tick this as solved. Cheers.

Comment: @xaxazak It is a commonly used idiom to add such `Enabler` parameter to templates (it should be automatically deduced most of the time), but it may be an issue if you need to use `SBar` as a template template argument. Maybe if you could elaborate on why it is annoying and I might be able to propose a more appropriate solution?

Comment: Mostly it's modularity. SBar is already used frequently (in 1-to-N containers), and shouldn't need to know about this new feature (N-to-N containers). But it's all my own code so I can update it, and it's not used in template-template stuff anywhere (although `SZug` uses a template-template parameter).

Comment: @xaxazak You only need to update the "main" declaration of `SBar`, you can even simply add a forward declaration prior to anything. Maybe I am missing something but it should not impact anything since the `Enabler` parameter is defaulted.

Comment: Ah yes, true. However, after implementing a few cases (eg: heap-allocated vs custom-allocated vs user-managed nodes) I found that moving `SZug` outside `SFoo` ultimately ends up being tidier because it only needs to be done once and it's 100% modular. However, it's good to know what options are there, and perhaps the question might help someone else. - I do wonder if C++ would benefit or suffer if the syntax in the question body was made legal.

Comment: Very good answer. Personally, I would have moved some of the auxiliary stuff to a detail namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the *effect* for which you're looking through the following (which prints out 0 1, BTW):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail
{   
    struct SZugBase{};
}   

template <typename tTYPE>
struct SFoo                                                                                                                                
{   
    struct SZug : public detail::SZugBase {}; 
};  

template<typename tType, bool IsFoo>
struct SBarBase
{   
    int value = 0;
};  

template<typename tType>
struct SBarBase<tType, true>
{   
    int value = 1;
};  

template <typename tTYPE>
struct SBar : public SBarBase<tTYPE, std::is_convertible<tTYPE, detail::SZugBase>::value>
{ /* stuff */ };

int main()
{   
    SBar<int> b0; 
    SBar<SFoo<int>::SZug> b1; 

    std::cout << b0.value << " " << b1.value << std::endl;
}
```

**Explanation**

First, we give `SZug` a regular-class base:

```
namespace detail
{   
    struct SZugBase{};
}   

template <typename tTYPE>
struct SFoo                                               
{   
    struct SZug : public detail::SZugBase {}; 
};
```

Note the following:

1. `SZugBase` is not parameterized by anything, so it is easy to refer to it independently of the parameter of `SFoo`
2. `SZugBase` is in a `detail` namespace, so, by common C++ conventions, you're telling clients of your code to ignore it.

Now we give `SBar` two base classes, specialized on whether something is convertible to the non-template base of `SZug`:

```
template<typename tType, bool IsFoo>
struct SBarBase
{   
    int value = 0;
};  

template<typename tType>
struct SBarBase<tType, true>
{   
    int value = 1;
};
```

Finally, we just need to make `SBar` a subclass of these bases (depending on the specialization):

```
template <typename tTYPE>
struct SBar : public SBarBase<tTYPE, std::is_convertible<tTYPE, detail::SZugBase>::value>
{ /* stuff */ };
```

Note that you don't specialize `SBar` here, you rather specialize the base classes. This effectively gives the same effect, though.

Comment: That works for `SBar<SFoo<int>> b1;`. Unfortunately, I'm looking for `SBar<SFoo<int>::` **`SZug`** `> b1;` (which AFAICT would still print 0).

Comment: @xaxazak You're right - I missed that detail in the question, but the principle applies. A few small changes in the details of the answer made this apply to your original intent. The main points are: 1. A non-template "detail" base, and 2. Specializing a base class based on whether it is convertible to this base.

Comment: Yep, that does fix the issue. I was crossing my fingers there might be a tidier way to do it. Both your solutions and Holt's could be accepted, but IMHO I think adding a fixer member type (Holt's method) is very slightly nicer than inheriting from a fixer struct.

Comment: Sure, you should accept whatever answer you think is the best (I'll read his answer too - always good to learn some new ideas).